# How to ignore/veto CDI producer method?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, java-ee-7

I know that I could us [ProcessAnnotatedType.veto()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/ProcessAnnotatedType.html#veto()) to ignore the bean.

However, I want to ignore the bean provided by a producer. e.g: I want to ignore this in Production enviroment

```
@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
@Development
EnvironmentDao developmentDao() {
    return new DevelopmentDao()
}
```

Anyone has clue?
Thank you.

@Update
Actually I have another solution like

```
@Development
@ApplicationScoped
class DevelopmentProducer {
  @Produces
  EnvironmentBean developmentBean = new EnvironmentBean() {
    @Override
    String getText() {
        return 'I am DevelopmentBean'
    }
  }

  @Produces
  @ApplicationScoped
  EnvironmentDao developmentDao() {
    return new DevelopmentDao()
  }
}
```

So that I could use ProcessAnnotatedType to ignore this Producer. However, I want know if there any method to just ignore the producer method instead of the entire producer?

Thank you.

Comment: If you have a `@Development` Qualifier, I suppose that you also have a kind of `@Production` Qualifier for EnvironnementDAO? You sould take a look at `@Alternative` to enable/disable beans.

Comment: @Rouliboy, actually the `@Development` is NOT a Qualifier. Besides, I am seeking for a solution without using the alternative. Thanks.

Comment: So what is `@Development`?

Comment: @RouliboyThe '@Development' is just a pain annotation that it is used to indicate the bean is a "development" bean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDI offers no straightforward way to disable a producer.

In fact, event `@Alternative` won't work. However, `@Specializes` would work as the bean class would be truly dropped and the producer therefore not found. But that's not what you are after anyway.

You can also make use of `Extension` and observe the [`ProcessProducer`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#process_producer) event. It does *not offer a veto method* but you can replace such producer with a new one fitting your needs in the `setProducer` method.